# C# generics question - generic interface constraint

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have some basic interface which is generics-driven:

```
public interface Inteface<T> {
   void Foo(T t);
}
```

Now I have some concrete implementation of this interface which is also generic:

```
public class InterfaceImpl<T> {
   public void Foo(T t) {
      // Whatever
   }
}
```

This looks OK, but now let's say I have other class:

```
public class Ololo {
   public void BadFunction<TShouldModelInterface>(TShouldModelInterface shouldModelInterface) {
      // Whatever
   }
}
```

And let's say I want to perform a check if `TShouldModelInterface` actually implements any of the possible `Interface<T>`.

If the interface wasn't generic, I would simply write something like `where TShouldModelInterface : Interface`.

**But is there any way to solve this problem if the interface is a `declared as Interface<T>`?**

Comment: I modified your title a bit so it is less generic

Comment: @Daniel Ahahah.. indeed less "generic"

Comment: In your example, ''InterfaceImpl<T>'' does not implement ''Inteface<T>'' (missing "r", btw). You should declare it as ''public class InterfaceImpl<T> : Inteface<T>''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Ololo {
   public void BadFunction<TShouldModelInterface, T>(TShouldModelInterface shouldModelInterface)
       where TShouldModelInterface : Interface<T>
   {
      // Whatever
   }
}
```